# Show Ulam's spiral

Tags: code-golf, primes

Similar to [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/769/3121) but in this one you need to write spiral starting from the center where:

- space means composite number
- `.`(dot) means prime number.

Size of the spiral can be given as parameter or on `stdin`. By size I mean side of square NxN and also N will be always odd.

Comment: Doesn't Ulam's spiral usually start with 1 in the middle and spiral outward, instead of spiraling inward?

Comment: Yeah, it's late so my brain is out of order.

Comment: By `size of the spiral` do you mean the number to go up to, or the number of spirals?

Comment: Also, are there limits on the number that may be input or is it 1 to infinity?

Comment: Square NxN and limit to 100000

Comment: Also similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1805796/code-golf-ulam-spiral

Comment: Wow, the J paper linked to in the original post of that question is amazing. 72 characters! `' .'{~1 p:>:|.(,~$/:@(+/\)@(_1&|.@((}:@(2:#>:@i.))#(<:@+:$1:,],_1:,-))))`

Answer (score 3):

### Python, 219 chars

```
N=input()
A={0:' '}
d=1j
x=1
for p in range(2,N*N+1):
 A[x]=' .'[all(p%i for i in range(2,p))]
 if abs(x.imag)==abs(x.real):x+=(1-1j)*(d==1);d*=1j
 x+=d
R=range(N)
for y in R:print''.join(A[x-N/2+(N/2-y)*1j]for x in R)
```

Works for any odd `N`.  For example:

```
$ echo 9 | ./ulam.py 
    . .  
 .     . 
. .   .  
   . . . 
  .  .. .
 . .     
.   .    
 .   .   
.     .
```

Answer (score 3):

**JavaScript (<s>240</s> <s>202</s> <s>195</s> 151 characters)**

Update: Another much smaller version without function (a lot of credits to @mellamokb):

```
for(x=3,e=d=f=a>>1,c=2;(x&1?x&2?++e<a-d:--e>d:x&2?++f<a-d-1:--f>d)||++x&3||d--;c
++)for(g=0;g<2*a*a;z[g+=c]=1)z[c]||z.getContext("2d").fillRect(e,f,1,1)
```

---

Works with this HTML:

```
<script>a = 50</script>
<canvas id=z width=50 height=50></canvas>
```

[25x25 example](http://jsfiddle.net/ngjXZ/) (zoomed in) - [800x800 example](http://jsfiddle.net/VkWVc/)

This new version now performs well and outputs the right size (NxN) for any odd `a`.

Found some small improvements (195 now). Thanks @mellamokb.

---

**[Old version:](http://jsfiddle.net/mpus6/)**

```
c=1;i=e=0;b={};for(d=[];c<a*a;){d.push("");for(i+=e+=2;i--;)d[Math.min(e-2,i)]+=
j();d.unshift("");for(i-=e;++i<e;)d[g=Math.max(0,i)]=j()+d[g]}x.innerHTML=d.join
("\n");function j(){if(f=!b[++c])for(h=c*c;h<2*a*a;h+=c)b[h]=1;return f?".":" "}
```

Currently takes variable `a` as input and outputs to an element with the id `x`:

```
<script>a = 50</script>
<pre id=x>
```

I used the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) for prime generation, which works really well. Output is quite slow so far though. Don't expect this to run for huge n yet.

Comment: I've used `Math.max(0,i)` trick in the past before thinking it was clever, but it's actually shorter to use a ternary: `d[g=i>0?i:0]`.  Same with `Math.min(e-2,i)` which should be rewritten as `d[i<e-2?i:e-2]`.

Comment: @mellamokb: My never version doesn't use `min` or `max` anymore. But thanks for the tip; it's good to remember these minor optimizations.

Comment: This *is* code-golf, so sacrifice a little performance to gain 3 chars: `for(g=0;g<2*a*a;b[g+=c]=1);` Likewise, move the whole `for` outside of the `if` and you can nix the `{}` for the `if`, saving another 2 characters :)

Comment: @mellamokb: wow, you're good at this. The second suggestion was even better because it can now be written as `b[c]||z.getContext`, saving 2 more characters.

Comment: Working through some ideas.  I have a few improvements to make, but I figured out this `eval(["--f>d","--e>d","++f<a-d-1","++e<a-d"][x%4])||++x%4||d--;`.  Basically this replaces all the `for(h()..` and also changes the condition on the main loop to just `d`. Then you must define `x=0` and subtract 1 from d to begin with since it's no longer in the condition.  Finally, inline `h()` since it's now only called once, and should be able to save about 10 characters (hopefully) :).  Will update with another idea that might save much more in a bit...

Comment: I figured out that if I started `x` at 3, then `++e` runs first so you no longer need `e=(..)+1`.  Also, then if I move the `eval(..)` to the front of the calls to `h()`, `d--` gets applied first, so everything is correct again.  However, then with a condition of `d` it stops one row early... so simply move the entire `eval()` and make it the condition of the main `for` loop!  Then we can also move the `++c` into the third part of the main `for` loop if we start `c` at 2 instead, saving another character.  Here's the final working 163-character solution:

Comment: `for(x=3,e=d=f=a>>1,c=2,b=[];eval(["--f>d","--e>d","++f<a-d-1","++e<a-d"][x%4])||++x%4||d--;c++)for(g=0;g<2*a*a;b[g+=c]=1)b[c]||z.getContext("2d").fillRect(e,f,1,1)`  (http://jsfiddle.net/SZp5v/2/)

Comment: @mellamokb: Nice one. This can be shortened even more by replacing the eval by ternary. And I think we can merge the 2 remaining loops, making this the least readable JavaScript code *ever*. I am working on it ...

Comment: that's what code golf is all about :P  love to see the outcome.. i do all JS answers on this site, u can look at some of my other ones.  i'm not satisfied until every last possible optimization is made ^_^

Comment: @mellamokb: Cut your version down to 151 chars. I also have [this version](http://jsfiddle.net/xCay7/) with only one loop, but it's bigger. But this is great now.

Comment: Shaved off 3 more characters by optimizing the inner loop to use multiples of c instead of adding c over and over: `for(i=0;a-i++;z[c*i]=1)`.  Basic idea using index `i` and multiply by `c`.  Also now only need to check `i<=a` instead of `g<2*a*a`.  To optimize further, I use `a-i` instead and increment in the condition so that `a-i==0` loop iteration is still performed.  I'm also looking into optimizing the movement further by using x/y direction vectors and combining the four movement operations and conditions into a single one...stay tuned! :)

Answer (score 2):

### Golfscript - 92 Characters

Based on my answer [here:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1810756/174728)

```
~.(:S+,:R{S\-:|;R{S-:$|>' .'1/[|$.|]2/@:d|~)$<!^=~:$;:y.*4*$-y-)2d*$y-*+:$,{)$\%!},,2==}%n}%
```

Answer (score 2):

### APL (85)

```
K[R↑+\(1+M-⍨N×M←⌈N÷2),(2/⍳N)/(2×N)⍴1(-N)¯1N]←K←⍳R←N×N←⎕⋄'. '[1+N N⍴K∊P/⍨P∊P∘.×P←1↓⍳R]
```

Explanation:

- Generating the spiral:

  - `K←⍳R←N×N←⎕`: Read N from the user. The array size N×N is stored in R. K is [1..R].
  - `(1+M-⍨N×M←⌈N÷2)`: The coordinate of the middle field.
  - `(2×N)1(-N)¯1N`: the delta coordinates for the next field (i.e. 1 right, up a line (so N fields to the left in a 1-dimensional array), then 1 left, then down a line.
  - `(2/⍳N)/`: duplicate the deltas to form an expanding spiral. 2/⍳N is `1 1 2 2 3 3 ... N N`, duplicating the deltas by these values gives `right up left left down down right right right...`
  - `R↑+\`: sum these values (giving absolute coordinates) and take the first R.
  - `K[`...`]←K`: assign K to K in the order given above. We now have K in spiral order.
- Generating the pattern:

  - `P/⍨P∊P∘.×P←1↓⍳R`: more or less the standard APL idiom for generating primes. P is [2..R], P∘.×P is a multiplication table for P. P∘.P therefore contains all composite numbers in the range [1..R]. P/⍨ then selects from P all values present in P∘.×P, giving a list of composite numbers.
  - `1+N N⍴K∊`: this selects from K all the composite numbers, giving a binary list in spiral order where there's an 1 if the number is composite. Then add 1 so that composite numbers are 2 and noncomposite (prime) numbers are 1. This is formatted as a N by N table.
  - `'. '[`...`]`: prime numbers (1) become `'.'` and composites (2) become `' '`.

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 13 bytes

```
UGlYLZp42*cwx
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/P9Q9J9InqsDESCu5vOL/f0sA)

A clockwise outward spiral which starts from the right.

### Explanation

```
    U       % convert char matrix to numeric or to general array / square
    G       % paste from user-input clipboard G
    l       % array of ones
    YL      % Create spiral matrix
    Zp      % is prime / totient function
    42      % number literal
    *       % array product (element-wise, singleton expansion)
    c       % convert to character array
    w       % swap elements in stack
    x       % delete elements
            % (implicit) convert to string and display
```

Answer (score 1):

### Python - 203 Characters

Similar to my answer [here:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1807536/174728)

```
x=input();y=x-1;w=x+y
A=[];R=range;k,j,s,t=R(4)
for i in R(2,w*w): 
 A+=[(x,y)]*all(i%d for d in R(2,i))
 if i==s:j,k=k,-j;s,t=s+t/2,t+1
 x+=j;y+=k
for y in R(w):print"".join(" ."[(x,y)in A]for x in R(w))
```