# "Snail" number sequence lookup

Tags: code-golf

You are given integers `N` and `M`, `1 <= N,M <= 10^6` and indexes `i` and `j`. Your job is to find the integer at position `[i][j]`. The sequence looks like this (for `N=M=5, i=1, j=3` the result is `23`):

```
 1  2  3  4  5
16 17 18 19  6
15 24 25 20  7
14 23 22 21  8
13 12 11 10  9
```

Shortest code wins. Good luck!

Comment: [Very closely related.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/769/print-nxn-spiral-of-ascending-numbers)

Comment: [As well as this.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/34591/spiral-in-the-grid)

Comment: You might want to clarify if M is the width or the height.

Comment: @MartinBüttner: I think N corresponds to i and M to j. Then you need only specify, that the snail starts at `i=j=0` and continues in `j=0` direction.

Comment: @M.Herzkamp either way, it's not 100% clear from the spec.

Comment: Does our code need to complete in a reasonable amount of time with a reasonable amount of memory for the given limits? I can definitely write *valid* code for those parameters, which just generates the spiral and looks up the value, but I don't actually have 4 TB of memory lying around.

Comment: Can we choose whether `i` and `j` index from 0 or 1?

Answer (score 6):

## Mathematica, <s>63</s> 55 bytes

```
f=If[#5<1,#+#4,f[#+#2,#3-1,#2,#5-1,#2-1-#4]]&;g=1~f~##&
```

This defines a function `g` which can be called like

```
g[5, 5, 1, 3]
```

I'm using a recursive approach. It uses up to *2(N+M)* iterations, depending on how far down the spiral the result is found. It does handle all inputs (up to `g[10^6,10^6,5^5-1,5^5]`, which requires the most iterations) within a few seconds, but for larger inputs, you'll need to increase the default iteration limit like

```
$IterationLimit = 10000000;
```

Basically, if `k` is the starting number of the spiral, I'm checking if the `j` index is `0` in which case I can just return `k + i`. Otherwise, I throw away the top row, rotate the spiral by 90 degrees (anti-clockwise), increment `k` accordingly, and look at the remaining spiral instead. We can move to the next spiral with the following mapping of parameters:

- *k<sub>n+1</sub> = k<sub>n</sub> + m<sub>n</sub>*
- *M<sub>n+1</sub> = N<sub>n</sub> - 1*
- *N<sub>n+1</sub> = M<sub>n</sub>*
- *i<sub>n+1</sub> = j<sub>n</sub> - 1*
- *j<sub>n+1</sub> = n<sub>m</sub> - i<sub>n</sub> - 1*

This assumes that *M* is the width and *N* is the height.

Comment: 51 bytes: `If[#5<1,#+#4,#0[#+#2,#3-1,#2,#5-1,#2-1-#4]]&[1,##]&`

Answer (score 3):

## Pyth, 25 bytes

```
D(GHYZ)R?+G(tHGtZt-GY)ZhY
```

This defines a function, `(`. Example usage:

```
D(GHYZ)R?+G(tHGtZt-GY)ZhY(5 5 1 3
```

prints `23`.

This is algorithmically identical to the Mathematica answer by Martin Büttner, though it was developed independently. As far as I can tell, that's the only good way to do it.

Note that Pyth cannot handle the full input range on my machine, it will overflow the stack and die with a segfault on large inputs.

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell, 44

```
z j i m n|j==0=i+1|0<1=z(n-i-1)(j-1)n(m-1)+n
```

this uses the regular recursive approach